# Equivalent javascript command to <script src="something1.json"></script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following line for reading a json file inside my html code:

```
<script src="something1.json"></script>
```

inside this json file I have something like this:

```
var varName = { .... }
```

This form of definition naturally defines a javascript variable names varName.

Suppose I have created a conditional inside my javascript code. In some cases I want to read the value of `varName` from "something1.json" and in some other cases from some other file (say "something2.json"). For this, I need a way to read the json inside my javascript (not inside html). I looked up the ways to read json inside javascript, but they seem far more complicated that what I need. Can you think of an easy way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: jquery has `$.getJSON`.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with JSON, but rather includes for different definitions of a javascript object literal.  Are you asking for ways to dynamically determine which file to include? If that is the case, can you share your current logic for determining which include to use?

Comment: *"inside this json file I have something like this"* Then it's not a JSON file; it's a *JavaScript* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts to this answer:

1. Answering the question you actually asked
2. Suggesting an alternative

The literal equivalent is:

```
$("<script>")
    .attr("src", varName)
    .appendTo($("script").first().parent());
```

That creates a script element that uss `varName` to get the `src` and appends it to the document. Once the file is retrieved, the JavaScript code inside it (your file contains JavaScript code, not JSON) will be run. That process is asynchronous. On all modern browsers, if you want to know when it completes, you can use a `load` handler:

```
$("<script>")
    .on("load", function() {
        // It finished loading
    })
    .attr("src", varName)
    .appendTo($("script").first().parent());
```

It's important to set `onload` **before** setting `src`, because otherwise, the `load` event can be raised before you hook it (yes, really; there's only one main JavaScript thread in browsers, but *browsers* are not single-threaded, and can look to see if there are handlers for the event asynchronously to the JavaScript code).

---

**Instead**, though, jQuery has [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

> **`jQuery.getScript( url [, success ] )`**
>
> Returns: `jqXHR`
>
> Description: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Example:

```
$.getScript(varName, function() {
    // It's loaded now
});
```